# Mac Book Pro Overheating

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a 5yr old Mac Book Pro. I didn't have it plugged and had shut it down. When I went to open it I found the whole laptop was heated and couldn't get it to turn on. I left it a while then plugged it in and finally it turned on but registered the battery was at 0 charge. Do I need a new battery or is it an internal problem. I left it for about 5 hours and restarted and recharged and seems to be okay again. I'm worried about damage to overheating. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated….Thanks

Comment: Sounds the lid-switch did not work, leaving your mac wake instead of putting it to sleep.

Comment: if there was a keyboard, mouse or monitor attached, the mac won't sleep and can get very hot

Answer (score 1):

As **[Rob](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/34561/rob)** said, your lid switch might be the problem.

I would suggest following steps:

- Reset your SMC and the PRAM/NVRAM.
- Run Apple Hardware test to see if it comes up with anything.
- Check your Pmset -g profile.

FYI:

There are 2 small magnets mounted on the lid (along the top edge)

You can find them by using paper clip.

On the opposite side (of closed lid) there are 2 sensors, that normally should last forever (unless you put a strong magnet on them so they are stuck now), but then there is nothing that does.